# APP_ROOT is defined incorrect

Tags: php

I have had quite some problems the last 5 days, and I am still stuck. Now I have been reading about the APP_ROOT, because I did not know what that was. I have a header.html, there is laying in the following path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/includes/header.html
```

I need to include that on every page I use. Before a user is logged in, my files is laying under:

```
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website
```

which also should be the ROOT of my website.
After a user is logged in, I have split my php files into folders.
Currently I am working on the file profile.php, which have the following path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/profile.php
```

I have tried to include the header.html in this file, but get the following error:

```
Warning: include(resources/includes/header.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/profile.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'resources/includes/header.html' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/profile.php on line 2
```

After asking about this on stackoverflow, I started reading about define a ROOT. I am not all confident with it, but here is what I get.

I am working in profile.php. I added:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Here I get that my root is: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`. As I see it, the root should be: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website`, so how can I change that?

When I run

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

I get the place of my file is located in:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth
```

That is correct.

So the problem for me, as I see it, that the error is caused because my ROOT is not defined. How can I define the root, so it changed from `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website` ?

I hope somebody can help me, so I can get on with my project.

Updated:
So My header is called now, and I am now working on the CSS and JS part, that I need to call in my header. So I set this in my header now . Is it something like this?

[image]

Comment: Don't get to focused on the names of things people help you with use. In your last question you were told to define a constant, you can name this whatever you want (but APP_ROOT makes sense). It was just to get the full path to where your application is located, so you can include files from that directory instead of including files from the relative paths of wherever you are in your aplpication.

Comment: ah okay, so my root is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`, which means the path to my file should be include '../resources/includes/header.html'. That would give the path: /`Applications/MAMP/htdocs//resources/includes/header.html` So I need to add ../ which would give: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs//website/resources/includes/header.html` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The original answer, for the original question

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` doesn't always help. Depending on the server software and its configuration it can contain a path that doesn't have anything in common with the path where your files are located. Don't rely on it! Using the technique presented below you can have more than one application hosted on the same server. This is useful when you use one development server to develop and test more than one application. Each application can be accessed using HTTP at different URLs, f.e. `http://localhost/app1/` and `http://localhost/app2`.

The easiest way to handle your situation is to use relative paths to specify the file you want to include and use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to build absolute paths from them.

The principle is very simple. If in file `web/a.php` you want to include file `include/b.php` then in `web/a.php` you write:

```
include dirname(__DIR__).'/include/b.php';
```

The magic constant `__DIR__` contains the directory where the current file (`web/a.php`) is located. We don't need to care where in the file system it is located; PHP takes care of it for us. The PHP function `dirname()` returns the parent directory of the path it receives.

Let's say our project is located in `/path-to-my-project/`. In `web/a.php`, the value of `__DIR__` is `/path-to-my-project/web` and `dirname(__DIR__)` returs `/path-to-my-project`. This is the root directory of our project.

The rest is piece of cake. Just append the location (inside the project) of the file you want to include. Let's notice that both `__DIR__` and `dirname()` produce paths that do not end with a slash (`/`)<sup>1</sup>. This is why the literal path of the included file must start with a slash: `/include/b.php`.

The technique can be used no matter the relative location of the included file to the includer. All you have to do is to use the correct number of calls to `dirname()` to reach the first common ancestor directory of both files (not necessarily the project root) and from that point you can reach the included file.

For example, if you want to include `include/b.php` in `web/admin/d.php` then `d.php` must contain:

```
include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/include/b.php';
```

But if you want to include `web/c.php` in `web/a.php` then you don't even need to call `dirname()`:

```
include __DIR__.'/c.php';
```

#### PHP 7 only

If you are using PHP 7 then you can compact a list of nested calls to `dirname()` into a single call by passing the number of levels to go up as its second argument:

```
// Any version of PHP
include dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))).'/include/b.php';


// Only PHP 7 and newer
include dirname(__DIR__, 3).'/include/b.php';
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There is an exception to this rule: if the produced path is the root directory (`/`) then the value of `__DIR__` and the value returned by `dirname()` is not the empty string but `/` (which **ends** with a slash).

### Update to the answer to match the update of the question (regarding the CSS and JS files)

The URLs you write in the HTML header in order to load the CSSs and JSs are a different story. They are (complete or partial) URLs, not paths on the local drive (as opposed to the first part of the answer where `include` uses paths of local files.)

My example above is a typical configuration of a web application. The web server is configured to serve the files from the `web/` directory. That is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is `/path-to-my-project/web`. When the user asks for `http://localhost/a.php`, the server loads and runs `/path-to-my-project/web/a.php`.

Only the files stored in `web/` and its subdirectories are accessible through HTTP. You put there only the files that are meant to be accessible: the pages of your applications and the resources (images, scripts, style sheets). All the files that are not to be used on their own (are included by other files) must be located outside the `web/` directory. In `include/`, for example.

The resources are usually located in subdirectories of the `web/` directory; images in `images/`, scripts in `js/` and stylesheets in `style/` or `css/` but this is not a rule; each project uses its own names.

They can be accessed using partial URLs: images as `<img src="/images/file1.jpg">`, stylesheets as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css">`, scripts as `<script src="/js/script1.js">`. The links to other pages are written as `<a href="/m.php">` (`m.php` is located in `web/`) or `<a href="/admin/login.php"> (`login.php`is located in`web/admin/`, of course).

The browser will compute the complete URLs from them by using the current protocol and host name. For example, in order to load `/js/script1.js` the browser computes its complete URL (which is `http://localhost/js/script1.js`) and asks the server for it. The server (`localhost`) receives a request for the resource `/js/script1.js`. It knows that the site root (`/`) is mapped to directory `/path-to-my-project/web`, computes the full file path in the file system as `/path-to-my-project/web/js/script1.js` and returns its content.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the very good explenation. I am starting to understand it now. It works for me now when I write like this: `<?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>`. All the CSS and JS is still not called from my header.php, so I also have to do something with those.

Comment: @McDuck4 I updated my answer. You updated your question by adding another question to the original one. The original question deals with file system paths. The new one is about URLs. Maybe the problems seem related to you but they are different issues. In the future, when you have another question please put it in a new post, even if it is related to the original one. You can put a link to the first question into the second one for the readers to understand the full context.

Comment: That is true, to be honest I didnt think about that. Thank you a for your answers and time on this. I really appriciate it. I tried to do that with the css and js, but it is not working. So I will look some more into it, and then post a new question in some hours, if it is not working. Thank you again

Comment: I have a really hard time to set an answer to this question, because both answers here is so good. I learned a lot from both answers, so I will let it up to the viewers on this threat in the future. I gave both an arrow up

Answer (score 1):

You use `APP_ROOT` for defining Application Root, and this make sense.

But for php `APP_ROOT` is a generic constant, without any particular significance.

To work with included files, there is a dedicated function, `set_include_path`:

```
$includePath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/includes';
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $includePath );
include 'header.html';
```

or:

```
$includePath = APP_ROOT . '/resources/includes';
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $includePath );
include 'header.html';
```

Note the use of `get_include_path()` and `PATH_SEPARATOR` inside the function call: with `get_include_path()` we append new include path to existing paths, without overwriting; `PATH_SEPARATOR` is a predefined constant that allow your script to work on different OS with different path separator.

---

[Edit:] Now you have the problem with relative URLs inside your headers file. I suggest you to replace it with dynamic Root-Relative URLs.

These are your absolute Paths:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/profile.php
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/includes/header.php
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

Assuming your Document Root is '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs', your final URL is:

```
http://hostname/website/resources/auth/profile.php
```

So, to properly works with any browser, all links inside include files must refer to 'http://hostname/website/resources/auth/' if relatives, or to 'http://hostname' is Document Root relatives.

Simply put Root-Relative path into your included files:

To refer to `bootstrap.min.css` — i.e. — you have to write:

```
$url = '/website/resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Obviously, this will works only if on same site / Document Root. If you intend use your css in different sites, you need to insert the complete absolute URL, because php can't know by itself something outside the Document Root. In this case you have to write:

```
$url = 'http://hostname/website/resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css';
```

( `$url` is the string to insert in `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag )

**Note** that if your real Document Root is '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website' you have to remove '/website' from above example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My header is called here. What I do not understand is why my external CSS and JS is not called in my header.html. I could of course add ../../ in header to the CSS, but that would result in the files in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs//website/`would not work

Comment: CSS and JS path are called by the browser, not by php: so - if they have a relative path, the browser try to load path relative of **current page url**.

Comment: So I need to add ../../ to my CSS no matter what? One of the path for the CSS looks like this: `<link href="resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`. How could I call that then?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and answer. Would that mean in header.html, my path to the css should be: 
`$baseUrl = substr( __DIR__, strlen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ) );
$css     = "$resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css";`

Comment: With `.html` you have to write directly the path (preferable Root-Relative, otherwise if you include it from another script your url can fail again). Otherwise you can rename it to `header.php` and then insert above code. You have to decide what method to follow. Maybe the easy way is to manually insert Root-Relative path, if you do no plan to change it position: `/resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css` leaving untouched header file name and ignoring my answer edit.

Comment: I would like to change it to header.php. When I change header.html to header.php, I get the same error again. Works on all other pages, except where I added: 
`<?php
$includePath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/includes';
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $includePath );
include 'header.php';
?>` Is there any way that you could make a full example, how to add the header.php and where and how to link to `resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`, how you would do it.

Comment: Thank you a lot again for your time and explenation. I am starting to get it now. I will try to play around with the CSS. I have something to go out from now. I will just try it out

Comment: No. I write: “url is the string to insert in `<link rel="stylesheet">`"  Simply write `<link href="/website/resources/etc/...">`. If you use `$url` then you have to echo it. But write directly the url.

Comment: Thank you a lot for all your time and efford to make this work. Axiac pointed out that it was another question with the js and css, so I will try to play arond with it, and then post a new question. Thank you a lot again for your help.

Comment: I have a really hard time to set an answer to this question, because both answers here is so good. I learned a lot from both answers, so I will let it up to the viewers on this threat in the future. I gave both an arrow up