# wrong path after dirname and folder structure

Tags: php, html, css

As you can see on the picture below, home.php is laying in the root folder "website". So I can easily call my CSS and JS with `<?php include 'resources/includes/header.php'; ?>`from the home.php. I had a question here [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111508/app-root-is-defined-incorrect#36112325), because I could not call my header.php from registernumbers.php That got solved with this, which mean my header is called now:

```
<?php include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
```

[image: Folder structure]

So the problem is now, that in my header.php I have a lot of links to CSS and JS, which I am using for all my sites. I will just show a few here:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">               
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/core/theme.css" >                                   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap-reset.css">            


<!--External CSS-->
<link href="assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<!-- External JS -->     
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/library/parallax-slider/js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"></script>
```

From home.php those it is working fine:

```
<?php include 'resources/includes/header.php'; ?>
```

But when I update the registernumbers.php the CSS and JS is not loaded. To make it work I can add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
```

But the problem now is home.php is not calling CSS and JS, because I change the path.

Is there a way to solve this, so I can include my header.php, and get the scripts there is in there, no matter where the php file I have to use is stored?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, the problem is with relative links/paths? Then add `<base href="http://www.mywebsite.com/">` to the header to specify a default URL to all links in your website

Comment: It works :-) 5 days work is over now. Thank you a lot.